# Template that returns a type

Tags: c++

My goal is to decide a type passed to a template class at compile time.

Here's some pseudocode:

```cpp
// Definition
template<size_t BitCount>
get_type<BitCount> {
    if (BitCount <= 8)  return uint8_t;
    if (BitCount <= 16) return uint16_t;
    if (BitCount <= 32) return uint32_t;
    if (BitCount <= 64) return uint64_t;
}

template<typename T>
class C {
...
};

// Usage
const size_t bit_count = 7;
C c = C<get_type<bit_count>>();
```

I think it should be possible to do it since the `bit_count` is known at compile time, but I'm having a hard type finding an example of this idiom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template <auto bitCount>
using UInteger = 
  std::conditional_t<bitCount <= 8, std::uint8_t,
    std::conditional_t<bitCount <= 16, std::uint16_t,
      std::conditional_t<bitCount <= 32, std::uint32_t, 
        std::conditional_t<bitCount <= 64, std::uint64_t,
          void>>>>;
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution that is very similar to your approach is to return a value of the type at compile time and using `decltype` to let the compiler figure out the corresponding type. This requires C++17:

```
template<size_t BitCount>
constexpr auto get_type() {
    if constexpr (BitCount <= 8)  return uint8_t{};
    else if constexpr (BitCount <= 16) return uint16_t{};
    else if constexpr (BitCount <= 32) return uint32_t{};
    else if constexpr (BitCount <= 64) return uint64_t{};
}
```

and it can be used like this:

```
constexpr size_t bit_count = 7;

decltype(get_type<bit_count>()) b; //b is uint8_t!

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b), uint8_t>);
```

Comment: Can this method be used like so `constexpr size_t bit_count = 7; C c = C<get_type<bit_count>>();`?

Comment: @andrey it would look more like this instead: `auto c = C<decltype(get_type<bit_count>())>();`

Comment: @andrey You can do so if you encapsulate the return type in an alias inside a `struct` like in my post: e.g. `C c = C<UInt_t<bit_count>>();`

Answer (score 2):

In C++17 and on-wards I'd create a **struct** like this

```
template<std::size_t BitCount>
struct UInt {    
  static constexpr auto get_type() {
    static_assert((BitCount > 0) && (BitCount <= 64), "Numbers can only be up to 64 bit");
    if constexpr (BitCount <= 8) {
      return std::uint8_t{};
    } else if constexpr (BitCount <= 16) {
      return std::uint16_t{};
    } else if constexpr (BitCount <= 32) {
      return std::uint32_t{};
    } else {
      return std::uint64_t{};
    }
  }
  using type = decltype(get_type());
};
```

which uses the **return type of a `static constexpr` function** to define an alias **`type`** for the wished data type with `decltype`. With `static_assert` you can make sure that `0` is excluded. Then you can define a more convenient **alias** similar to what C++17 does with [`std::enable_if_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

```
template <std::size_t BitCount>
using UInt_t = typename UInt<BitCount>::type;
```

You can then use it like

```
UInt_t<7> var {};
```

or in your case:

```
C c = C<UInt_t<bit_count>>();
```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U3DJuq920VxFuTwq)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to using a template function and `decltype()` on the return value, you can use template specialization with SFINAE to declare a custom type trait that defines the appropriate data type given a supported bit size.  Plus, this works in C++11 and C++14, whereas `if constexpr` requires C++17:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>

// Definitions

template<size_t BitCount, typename Enable = void>
struct bit_type
{
};
 
template <size_t BitCount>
struct bit_type<BitCount, typename std::enable_if<std::islessequal(BitCount, 8)>::type>
{
    using type = uint8_t;
};

template <size_t BitCount>
struct bit_type<BitCount, typename std::enable_if<std::isgreater(BitCount, 8) && std::islessequal(BitCount, 16)>::type>
{
    using type = uint16_t;
};

template <size_t BitCount>
struct bit_type<BitCount, typename std::enable_if<std::isgreater(BitCount, 16) && std::islessequal(BitCount, 32)>::type>
{
    using type = uint32_t;
};

template <size_t BitCount>
struct bit_type<BitCount, typename std::enable_if<std::isgreater(BitCount, 32) && std::islessequal(BitCount, 64)>::type>
{
    using type = uint64_t;
};

template <size_t BitCount>
using bit_type_t = typename bit_type<BitCount>::type;

// Usage

template <typename T>
class C
{
    ...
};

const size_t bit_count = 7;
auto c = C<bit_type_t<bit_count>>();
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/JtD1C8)